# Generate a WLAN signal in Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink, wifi, receiver

I am looking for some tool, through which I could generate / simulate the WLAN ( IEEE 802.11 b PHY layer ) signal.

My preference would be to generate in Matlab. Any useful links or idea how I can do it would be of great help.

Thanks,
Kiran

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5331-rohde-schwarz-smp-signal-generators
Basically you need a microwave ISM.
Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I donot have the background in "Matlab Instrument Driver Editor". Is it possible to generate WIFI Signal through this ? I plan to read the WIFI signal in the workspace( as a variable). Is it also possible to write matlab code as well ?

Comment: I honestly havent tried it myself, but according to the description - yes, you should be able to generate a 2.4G microwave signal (That's what 802.11b essentially is). In the worst case you will need to write a function to generate it yourself (not hard if you know how the wave is described). You will probably not be able to read the signal (if i understand correctly you want to read it from your wireless card? - not sure if matlab supports that... you may want to ask about it on matlab forums). You may have to consider writing it in other high level language if thats what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party here, but an alternative to driving a (more expensive) signal generator is to drive a cheaper alternative. The latest [Simulink Communications Blockset](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/comm/ref/a1083164701.html#bsnml9_) (v5.0 - r2010b) includes support for [Ettus Research](http://www.ettus.com)'s USRP2, which can be driven to create Wifi (802.11a/b/g) phy layer signals (with the appropriate daughterboard - e.g. the RFX2400 and/or the XCVR2450). Note that the current release of the blockset does *not* support the newer USRP N210, or some of the newer daughterboards that require the UHD driver (e.g. the WBX, SBX, etc.) - although I have heard that such support may make into the next release. Note that this uses Simulink rather than Matlab to interface to the radio - but since Matlab and Simulink can pass variables back and forth you should be able to achieve what you want. Note that the USRP-family of radios are general purpose SDRs (software-defined radios), so once you discover how to program them (e.g. via Simulink, or GNURadio, or completely custom software if you wish), you can make them generate any RF signal within the available instantaneous bandwidth (e.g. about 25Mhz in the USRP2, or higher if you want to re-program the FPGA), and at carrier frequencies supported by the daughterboard you supply.